# Select timestamp for aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
products
id | actual_price

prices_history
id| product_id| price| timestamp

products.id = prices_history.product_id
```

I need to `select products.id, max(prices_history.price) and one latest timestamp for max(prices_history.price).`

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT p.id, max_price, actual_price, max_price_time                       
FROM products p                                                
JOIN (SELECT max(price) as max_price, product_id
      FROM prices_history                              
      WHERE timestamp > '2019-02-01'                             
      GROUP BY product_id) h                             
      ON  h.product_id = p.id
JOIN (SELECT timestamp as max_price_time,  product_id, price                           
      FROM prices_history
      ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) h2                            
      ON  h2.product_id = p.id AND h2.price = max_price;
```

But it returns nothing

Interestingly, without second JOIN I am getting many results. So I guess that ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 in the second JOIN somehow breaks everything.
But without LIMIT I don't know how to get only one latest timestamp where price has been MAX?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (ph.product_id) ph.*
from prices_history ph
order by price desc, timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 0):

use row_number()

```
  withe cte as

 (  SELECT p.*,ph.*,
   row_number()over(partition by p.id order by  timestamp desc,price desc)rn                     
    FROM products p join prices_history ph on p.id = ph.product_id
 ) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your problem is with the fact that your 2nd subquery doesn't use any filters and you essentially always find the same latest timestamp (of all timestamps, not just for that one product), which doesn't match up with any of the maximum_prices (so max prices of each product is never on the latest timestamp).

Disregard my previous answer. It might be because I haven't touched pure SQL in a while, but I couldn't get that logic implemented through grouping in a single query (tried doing it in postgress SQLfiddle). I could have sworn I could filter a grouped query by max values within a group.... Anyways, I tried rewriting that query and I see now why you used suqueries.

It is still the exact same problem (no filters). Adding grouping to your 2nd sub-query fixes the problem. [SQLfiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5fe47/32) to demonstrate:

```
select p1.id, p1.max_price, p2.max_date 
from ( select id, max(price) as max_price from prod group by id ) as p1  
  inner join  ( select id, price, max(date) as max_date from prod group by id, price ) as p2 
    on p1.id = p2.id and p1.max_price = p2.price
```

At this point adding another inner join before first 2 subqueries should be simple enough.

Comment: Your guessing makes sense to me! I didn't show a couple of filters but if I remove them and expand the selection range, I can get the result where max_price on the latest timestamp). So it is not given that actual_price is not max_price therefore 'having actual_price = max(price)' clause not needed. Besides, in your suggestion max(timestamp) is the latest timestamp, while max(price) can happen earlier, i.e. on different timestamp

Comment: I tested my own code in sqlFiddle and it does not even compile.. Either I screwed up with my suggestion or postgress does not support the kind of filtering I was suggesting. Either way, I've rewritten the query and this one works (you'll have to change the names).